# How to use or convert xamarin.forms pcl into xamarin native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i have a xamarin project into Xamarin.forms PCL and i want to convert/use it into xamarin.forms native, how can i do it. if there is a way please guide me to it.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to port your project from PCL to .NET Standard?

Comment: You could check the tutorial about `Convert A PCL Project Into .NET Standard Project` from the link. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-tip-easiest-way-to-convert-a-pcl-project-to-net-standard-projec/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require to edit your project file and set the target framework to netstandard(2/2.1). Then if you reload the project, visual studio will perform automatic migration for you.

A file with migration log will be generated, which may contain information about incompatible packages with new framework. Old project file(.csproj) will also be backed up automatically.

You should also delete AssemblyInfo.cs and packages.json files. All nuget packages and references need to add again.

Please refer below guides :

[Upgrade PCL to .NET Standard Class Library](https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/)

[How to Convert a Portable Class Library to .NET Standard and Keep Git History](https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/)